# Text generated with rmagick looks ugly

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, rmagick, annotate

I'm trying to generate some text in an image that will be embedded in an email.
I would like to look as much as possible as the other text in the message body; so I tried:

```
i = Image.new(500, 100)
d = Draw.new
d = d.annotate(i, 0,0,0,25,nombre){
 self.font = "Arial-Regular"
 self.pointsize = 12
 self.text_antialias = true
}
```

but the output is awful (see [output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QTqu.png))

I'm using Ubuntu, I've installed msttcorefonts (Arial appears on `convert -list font`). I've also tried using other fonts/font_families and turning off `text_antialias` with the same  luck

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly not the DPI, it's that ImageMagick is doing both stroke and fill for fonts. Try `d.stroke('transparent')` on your graphics context, and then you should just see the fill, which is the actual region the font was trying to draw, rather than its outline.

Answer (score 0):

Make the image bigger and increase your DPI.  Or, make the image bigger and use a larger pointsize.  To my eye, it looks as though your text is aliased simply because it is so small.

Comment: Imagemagick uses dpi=72.  I think Chrome uses dpi=96.  Therefore, if Chrome has a larger dpi, the characters will render with more pixels.  Look closely at your example.  The chrome characters are indeed just a bit taller.  Moreover, the hinting looks different on the two examples.  Remember, Linux has two font configuration systems.  X uses one, gnome uses another.  It's a mess. [look here](http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/fonts/)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I found that if I set a `background_color` (any!) fonts look better. see: 

[Without background_color](http://i.imgur.com/dd5c4cY.png) / 

[With background_color](http://i.imgur.com/bQDsgrw.png)

I'm going to report a bug to rmagick, something looks bad here..

Thanks for the link!

Comment: I noticed the same issue on my system.  Was your bug report ever handled?